# I want to show my content on mouseover id #topics article a and class name what is to be show is .topics-active

Tags: jquery, mouseevent, mouseover, onmouseover

**Hi,** I have container, contain numbers of box images. when i mouseover the image hide box will appear on the image. but when i use this script all the box get open...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#topics article a').mouseover(function(){
        $('.topics-active').show()

        })

    })
```

the html code is

```
   <div class="">
   <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 visionbx1 padlft0px padrgt0px"><a href="#" title="ViSION"><img src="images/videoscimg.jpg" class="img-responsive"><h3 class="textarticle">entreprenuership</h3></a>
      <div class="topics-active" style="display: block;"><a href="#" title="ViSION">    
   <h4>Inspiration</h4>   
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
   <button>Follow</button>
   </a></div>
     </div>

     <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 visionbx1 padlft0px padrgt0px"><a href="#" title="ViSION"><img src="images/videoscimg.jpg" class="img-responsive"><h3 class="textarticle">entreprenuership</h3></a>
      <div class="topics-active" style="display: block;"><a href="#" title="ViSION">
   <h4>Inspiration</h4>
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
   <button>Follow</button>
   </a></div>
     </div>

    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 visionbx1 padlft0px padrgt0px"><a href="#" title="ViSION"><img src="images/videoscimg.jpg" class="img-responsive"><h3 class="textarticle">Idea</h3></a>
     <div class="topics-active" style="display: block;"><a href="#" title="ViSION">
   <h4>Inspiration</h4>
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
   <button>Follow</button>
   </a></div>
    </div><!--end of section 1-->
    </div>`
```

Answer (score 0):

you are using class selector $('.topics-active').show(), which will show all elements with class topics-active.

You need to select that particular div using something like below. Here this is current anchor element

```
$(this).prev('div[".topics-active"]').show();
```

Comment: this is not working... nothing open when i add this line instead of  $('.topics-active').show()

$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#topics article a').mouseover(function(){
  $(this).prev('div[".topics-active"]').show();
  
  })
 
 })

Comment: I think there might be a syntax typo error in my answer. try $(this).prev("div['.topics-active']").show(); or $(this).closest("div['.topics-active']").show();